# Add, insert, and delete entries on single page with Angular

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I'm looking for a general good practice solution to this problem. I don't need any specific code, and I've already come up with hacky ways to do it.

So I have a group of users (group1) in a database. Each user has a first name, last name, and hometown.

The current setup is each row is three pre-filled input text boxes (firstname, lastname, hometown), and a delete button. Below all the rows, an 'add' button, which adds a row of blank text boxes. The admin can edit, delete, or add multiple rows, then press save (or cancel). Now what?

The simplest implementation I thought of was to send it all of the data back to the server (.NET MVC) in a form. Then I delete all of those users (group1) from the database, and insert into the database what I find in the form. That way I don't have to worry about what's an insertion, deletion, or edit.

This is clearly not the best way to do it. Any suggestions? Clearly I should just be sending back data that changes - the edits, insertions and deletions. Would using Angular.js with this offer any helpful patterns?

Answer (score -1):

Create a parent List in Javascript for Users. Add child lists to it. 'editedUsers', 'deletedUsers', 'newUsers'. Populate the lists and send them to server.

Basically you are just keeping a track of all the operations performed by the ADMIN; till he hits save button.